# Illustrator scripting

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script for an active doc in Illustrator. The active doc already has the spot swatch for "LEAD" in it. All the paths I have to set and symbols need to be set to this swatch. I have worked my way around it by deleting the swatch then re-adding it to the doc. This works for all my paths and objects created. There are 3 symbols in the active doc that are being placed by scrip, that are already set to the spot swatch. When my script deletes the swatch it resets the symbol to 100% black process. Is there a way to pull the swatch from the active doc?All path items reqiure the leadSpotColor variable to set that color. The LEAD swatch already exist in the active doc. If i do not add the swatch remove line before hand it errors out, but the swatch remove line sets my symbols already in the active doc to 100% process black, and they also need to be set to the LEAD swatch.

```
if ( app.documents.length = "LEAD" ) {

   swatchToDelete = app.activeDocument.swatches["LEAD"];
   swatchToDelete.remove();
   }

var leadSpot = doc.spots.add();
var leadSpotColor = new CMYKColor(); 
leadSpotColor.cyan = 0;
leadSpotColor.magenta = 0;
leadSpotColor.yellow = 0;
leadSpotColor.black = 100;
leadSpot.name = "LEAD";
leadSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
leadSpot.color = leadSpotColor;
var leadSpotColor = new SpotColor();
leadSpotColor.spot = leadSpot;
```

Comment: Can you please post code. It is really difficult to say what you are trying to do without your code.

Comment: if ( app.documents.length = "LEAD" ) {
 
   swatchToDelete = app.activeDocument.swatches["LEAD"];
   swatchToDelete.remove();
   }

var leadSpot = doc.spots.add();
var leadSpotColor = new CMYKColor(); 
leadSpotColor.cyan = 0;
leadSpotColor.magenta = 0;
leadSpotColor.yellow = 0;
leadSpotColor.black = 100;
leadSpot.name = "LEAD";
leadSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
leadSpot.color = leadSpotColor;
var leadSpotColor = new SpotColor();
leadSpotColor.spot = leadSpot;

Comment: Please do not post it in a comment, it is impossible to read what your code is! Post it in the question. You can make it as code by leaving 4 spaces before putting the code, or select all the code and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: How do I edit the question to post it  as code

Comment: Just click the small `edit` button under your question's tags. Then you can make any edit you want for your question.

Comment: OK figured it out. All path items reqiure the leadSpotColor variable to set that color. The LEAD swatch already exist in the active doc. If i do not add the swatch remove line before hand it errors out, but the swatch remove line sets my symbols already in the active doc to 100% process black, and they also need to be set to the LEAD swatch.

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: Yeah, so that whoever reads your question afterwards, does not have to refer to the comment, and it becomes much more clear.

Comment: Damn. I thought maybe you had a possible solution. No?

Comment: Yeah, but even if I do not have a possible solution, why did you remove the code and the explanation. You have not got an answer possibly because no one is understanding your question. The more clear the question is, the more details there are, the higher the chance of getting an answer is.

Comment: Thanks, +1, hope you get a solution. Just next time, do this as you post this question, so that you do not have to waste time for putting code in your question.

Comment: I accidentally removed the code when adding in the information you said to add. Thank you for the advice. It is hard to find any resources on illustrator scripting online, so hopefully i will find it here.

Comment: Yep, SO (Stack Overflow), is a really good place for asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to delete the swatch if you can just edit it ?

```js
var main = function(){
 
 var doc,
 leadClr, c;
 
 if(!app.documents.length) return;

 doc = app.activeDocument;
 
 leadClr = getLeadColor(doc);
 
 if ( leadClr===null ) {
  var leadSpot = doc.spots.add();
  var leadSpotColor = new CMYKColor(); 
  leadSpotColor.cyan = 0;
  leadSpotColor.magenta = 0;
  leadSpotColor.yellow = 0;
  leadSpotColor.black = 100;
  leadSpot.name = "LEAD";
  leadSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
  leadSpot.color = leadSpotColor;
  var leadSpotColor = new SpotColor();
  leadSpotColor.spot = leadSpot;
 }
 else {
  c =  leadClr.color.spot.color;
  c.cyan = 0;
  c.magenta = 0;
  c.yellow = 0;
  c.black = 100;
 }
};

var getLeadColor = function(doc){
 var clrs = doc.swatches,
 n = clrs.length;
 
 while (n-- ) {
  if ( clrs[n].name=="LEAD" ) return clrs[n];
 }

 return null;
}
main();
```

I would recommend adding some prevention mechanism like ensure swatch is actually a spot prior to reach teh spot property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all first line of your code is wrong

```
if ( app.documents.length = "LEAD" )
```

How you can compare length with string "LEAD", its should be a number and also in **if** statement we use conditional operator and what you are doing is assigning value in **if** statement.

Here is the script for LEAD spot, that will give you spot color if exist otherwise it will create new spot color with name "LEAD"

```
function main() {
    var currentDocument;
    var leadSpotColor;
    if (!app.documents.length) {
        alert("No document is open");
        return;
    }
    currentDocument = app.activeDocument;
    leadSpotColor = getLeadSpotColor(currentDocument);
    applyColorToAllPath(leadSpotColor, currentDocument);
}

function getLeadSpotColor(currentDocument) {
    try {
        var leadSpotColor = currentDocument.spots.getByName('LEAD')
        return leadSpotColor;
    } catch (e) {
        var color = new CMYKColor();
        color.cyan = 0;
        color.magenta = 0;
        color.yellow = 0;
        color.black = 100;
        var newSpot = currentDocument.spots.add();
        newSpot.name = "LEAD";
        newSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
        newSpot.color = color;
        var leadSpotColor = new SpotColor();
        leadSpotColor.spot = newSpot;
        return leadSpotColor;
    }
}

function applyColorToAllPath(leadSpotColor, currentDocument) {
    // Change code as per your requiremnt. I just handled for pathItems. You can similary for symbols.
    var pathItems = currentDocument.pathItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < pathItems.length; i++) {
        pathItems[i].filled = true;
        pathItems[i].fillColor = leadSpotColor;
        pathItems[i].stroke = true;
        pathItems[i].strokeColor = leadSpotColor;
    }
}

main();
```